# Creating class that extends TCPDF with WhiteOctoberBundle

Tags: php, symfony, tcpdf

For creating PDF files in Symfony I'm using [TCPDF](https://packagist.org/packages/tecnick.com/tcpdf) class with [WhiteOctoberTCPDFBundle](https://github.com/whiteoctober/WhiteOctoberTCPDFBundle). Both installed via composer.

I need to create custom header and footer by extending TCPDF class, like mentioned in [TCPDF documentation](http://www.tcpdf.org/examples/example_003.phps).

But the only working solution for me is to extend TCPDF class directly in vendors and then set MYPDF class as default in WhiteOctoberBundle inside getConfigTreeBuilder() method in vendor/whiteoctober/tcpdf-bundle/DependencyInjection/Configuration.php.

So my Configuration.php file looks like this:

```
public function getConfigTreeBuilder()
    {
        $treeBuilder = new TreeBuilder();
        $rootNode = $treeBuilder->root('white_october_tcpdf');

        $rootNode
            ->children()
                ->scalarNode('file')->defaultValue('%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/tecnick.com/tcpdf/tcpdf.php')->end()
                ->scalarNode('class')->defaultValue('MYPDF')->end()
            ->end();

        $this->addTCPDFConfig($rootNode);

        return $treeBuilder;
    }
```

The problem is that extending TCPDF class directly in vendor is bad practice and it causes that MYPDF class disappears during every update of TCPDF Bundle. Where should I place MYPDF class so it would stay accessible for WhiteOctoberBundle and at the same time it won't be placed inside vendors folder?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bundle author here :-) This is in the [bundle documentation](https://github.com/whiteoctober/WhiteOctoberTCPDFBundle#using-tcpdf), but for a quick reference:

1. Create your `MYPDF` class and place it somewhere within your normal Symfony2 code base - let's say in `src/Acme/DemoBundle/MYPDF.php`

   This class needs to extend the base TCPDF class, which is brought in via the vendors. You'll get an exception thrown if it's not.
2. In your `config.yml` or similar:

   ```
   white_october_tcpdf:
       class: 'Acme\DemoBundle\MYPDF'
   ```
3. You should be then able to use this as per the docs:

   ```
   $pdfObj = $container->get("white_october.tcpdf")->create();
   ```

   which will give you a new instance of your `MYPDF` class.

Answer (score 1):

Symfony official website suggests `AppBundle\Utils`

Source : http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/business-logic.html